# UPDATE OOP PDO PROBLEMS

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am pretty new to OOP and PDO and I am having problems with my function. Whenever I click on the update button it doesn't update but rather creates a new member for me.

```
public function updateAll($data){

   try {

        $r = $this->db->query("UPDATE addmember SET(
            Pic = '".$data[0]."',
            Firstname= '".$data[1]."',
            Lastname= '".$data[2]."',
            Age= '".$data[3]."',
            Gender= '".$data[4]."',
            Phonenumber='".$data[5]."',
            Location='".$data[6]."',
            Member='".$data[7]."',
            Department='".$data[8]."'

            WHERE id='".$data[9]."'

            )");
       if ($r) {
          return true;
       }
       else{
         return false;
       }

   } catch (PDOException $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();

   }

}
```

Comment: for the page this is what

Comment: the button are not finctioning

Comment: you seem to be missing the value of PDO - use prepared statements rather than embedding variables directly in the sql...

Comment: You're going to need to show us more code. What is calling that function? Are you sure it's calling the `updateAll` method? Do a `print_r($data);` at the top of that function and ensure it's being called.

Comment: Use this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp, first prepare next execute

Comment: Where you call your update method? Looks like the Problem is there. Not your update method is called, your insert method is called

Comment: Voting to close, no mcve

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but you could use PDO with prepared statements like this.

```
public function updateAll($data=false){
    try {
        if( !$data ) return false;

        $sql='update `addmember` set 
            `pic`=:pic,
            `firstname`=:firstname,
            `lastname`=:lastname,
            `age`=:age,
            `gender`=:gender,
            `phonenumber`=:phonenumber,
            `location`=:location,
            `member`=:member,
            `department`=:department
            where id=:id;';

        $params=array(
            ':pic'          =>  $data[0],
            ':firstname'    =>  $data[1],
            ':lastname'     =>  $data[2],
            ':age'          =>  $data[3],
            ':gender'       =>  $data[4],
            ':phonenumber'  =>  $data[5],
            ':location'     =>  $data[6],
            ':member'       =>  $data[7],
            ':department'   =>  $data[8],
            ':id'           =>  $data[9]
        );

        $stmt=$this->db->prepare( $sql );
        foreach( $params as $param => $value )$stmt->bindParam( $param, $value );

        return $stmt->execute();
       /*
           or, easier and quicker would be to ignore binding params and simply do:-
          return $stmt->execute( $params );
       */

    } catch( PDOException $e ) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```